# Results! 结果 vs 成果 vs 果实 vs 成就 vs 成绩

Tags: difference

So, this is quite the connundrum! This is how far I have got:

结果 - just means result, in a general sense

The following five words seem all to refer to success/achievement, and even after searching on the internet, I'm very unsure as to what the difference is: 成果, 成绩, 果实, 成就, 成功。

I thought 成绩 was the result exclusively from an exam (i.e. exam result), but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Also, 果实 is very confusing because you can apparently say 成功的果实, i.e. the results of one's success. But isn't that a double-statement? Success is by definition a result, right?

If anyone knows of a good way to distinguish between these words, I'd be extremely happy to hear it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I try to differentiate similar words, I always try to inspect the character inside to dig the nuances out.

结果: The process that plants bear fruits. It is natural.

成果: Involved your works.

成绩: Involved your works, and the result can be measured subjectively, usually can be compared with others.

果实: fruits. The specific things that represent the result.

成就: Achievements, honorable.

成功: success in general, honorable is not necessary.

> When to use 成功的果实?

Let's say I got the championship of the world cup, I am holding the cup and celebrating.

My coach talks to me: 享受你的成功果实吧.

Here 果实 means the cup.

胜利的果实

And then FIFA say that our team violate rules, the championship title would be taken back. I could say 我们的胜利果实被夺走了.

Here 果实 means the title.

Usually, you will see 胜利果实, 成功果实 is not common.

Finally, I will use all the words in one context.

我们成功了, 我们的最好成绩是世界杯冠军, 这是一个伟大的成就. 科学训练成果非凡, 场下努力付出, 场上自然收获了不起的果实.

Comment: Thanks Jacob - that is a really comprehensive answer and is a huge help!!!

Answer (score 0):

结果 means result. For example: 這是你想要的結果嗎?.

成果 means some things or quality of result you want. For example: 成果發表會。.

成就 means achievement. For example: 這個人有很高的成就。.

成績 means grade. For example: 他在這次的考試獲得好成績。.